# Fill the missing number puzzle

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

I have this puzzle that none of my colleagues (including me) can figure out and I can't sleep because of it :). Can someone please help:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What does the hollow ellipse correspond to?

Comment: "I can't sleep because of tit"... lol can't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be

> the missing number is $3$

---

### Explanation

If we denote the four numbers by $a,b,c,d$, in clockwise order, starting with the lower left position (so that in the left picture $a=2$, $b=8$, $c=14$ and $d=9$),
then these number satisfy the relation

> $d*a-(b/a) = c~~~~$  Indeed, $9*2-(8/2)=14$ in the left picture.
>
>  In the right picture, the unknown $x=?$ then should satisfy $x*3-(15/3)=4$, which yields the answer $x=3$.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir. But what is the purpose of the circle?

Comment: @Radoslav.Ivanov: I have no idea about the purpose of the circle/ellipse. Also, my answer is just a guess; there might be better answers that also explain the ellipse.

Comment: Also can you explain the relation between the numbers, because as I understand it the equations c = d*a - b/a, so d = b*c - b/a which is not 9...

Comment: But the equation c=da-b/a yields d=(b+ac)/a^2. In the left picture  this means 9=(8+2*14)/4, and in the right picture this means d=(15+3*4)/9=3.

Comment: With only 1 complete sample we could make many relations fit. Like a+b+c+d=33, which makes the answer 11. There's gotta be something something else, like the circle, that determines the right answer.